# is jBPM executionservice multi thread safe?

Tags: thread-safety, jbpm

is jBPM executionservice multi thread safe? That is can we call say

```
startProcessInstanceById
```

concurrently from multiple threads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is indeed multi-thread safe. I found it out through my own experiments.